# NuGet repo in TeamCity

Tags: mercurial, nuget, teamcity

I wonder if you can help me over here:
For some reasons, my NuGet packages were successfully built but they were using the previous version not the latest update.

For example:
For version 1.0 = I have property name = Jane
For version 2.0 = I updated the name property to = James but still getting Jane for the subsequent NuGet package updates.

I have checked the log that TeamCity actually did download the latest update from Mercurial server but still giving me the last version after build inside the package.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I knew what was wrong here.
I need to build the NuGet solution first and then continue with NuGet packaging and publishing in TeamCity.

I hope this answer will save somebody's time in the future.